# Plugin tutorial: Gazebo starts but not plugin

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm doing the Velodyne LiDAR plugin tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5), but I can't get Gazebo to recognize the plugin. I have copied the code from steps 2-4 and successfully built it using cmake and make, but when I run the scene using

```
cd ~/velodyne_plugin/build
gazebo ../velodyne.world
```

Gazebo just starts the scene without outputting anything to the terminal. I also tried adding the code supposed to spin the joint, as in step 5, with the same result. I even tried removing the plugin library file (`libvelodyne_plugin.so`) that I built altogether, while still having the line

```
<plugin name="velodyne_control" filename="libvelodyne_plugin.so"/>
```

in my .world-file and Gazebo still launches the scene just fine. I also tried adding another model (the Cessna air plane) to the .world-file, and that one appears as it should.

Any ideas?

EDIT: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, and I run Gazebo version 7.0.0

EDIT2: Using the --verbose tag gives the following output:

```
~/Developer/Gazebo/velodyne_plugin/build$gazebo ../velodyne.world --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.121.123
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.121.123
[Err] [Plugin.hh:165] Failed to load plugin libvelodyne_plugin.so: libvelodyne_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14091/plugin-tutorial:-gazebo-starts-but-not-plugin/) by [hassanbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2754/hassanbot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-08-09**:
Have you tried running gazebo in verbose mode? Just add --verbose to the command. Then update the question with the output.

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-08-10**:
And also check that your GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable is correctly set.

**Comment by [hassanbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2754/hassanbot/) on 2016-08-10**:
It was the environment variables that hadn't been set. Thanks! I updated the question with the verbose output and added the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem was I hadn't set the Gazebo environment variables. See this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components

---

Originally posted by [hassanbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2754/hassanbot/) with karma: 33 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MaKaNu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3957/makanu/) on 2017-10-16**:
Could specify this? I installed Gazebo-7 and started with the tutorial same as you. We are using gazebo 7 because we use a UR5 Modell which requires ver 7 instead of 8. I think my envirment variables are correct, but I'm not shure about which are the right variables.